# Adding fancy box to a WP theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox, gallery, lightbox

I'm fairly new to making my own WP themes. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to add a lightbox type functionality to it. I googled the topic extensively and the only decent tutorial I was able to find is: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/add-a-responsive-lightbox-to-your-wordpress-theme--wp-28100

It uses FancyBox. I tried following the instructions over and over again - no use. I don't get the FancyBox functionality on my images though - if I click on the image, it just opens up the full image's path, rather than a lightbox.

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm far from an expert when it comes to ensuing everything correctly.

If there is a better way to do it, or if Lightbox is considered better than Fancybox - I'm open to all sorts of suggestions and directions.

Here is my test page - http://www.aspenwebsites.com/lothlorien/gallery/

Basically, I created a 'lightbox' folder in my theme's 'inc' folder and dumped there all the source files I downloaded from the Fancybox Github.

Per the tutorial I then created lightbox.js file with the following content:

```
(function($) {

// Initialize the Lightbox for any links with the 'fancybox' class
$(".fancybox").fancybox();

// Initialize the Lightbox automatically for any links to images with extensions .jpg, .jpeg, .png or .gif
$("a[href$='.jpg'], a[href$='.png'], a[href$='.jpeg'], a[href$='.gif']").fancybox();

// Initialize the Lightbox and add rel="gallery" to all gallery images when the gallery is set up using [gallery link="file"] so that a Lightbox Gallery exists
$(".gallery a[href$='.jpg'], .gallery a[href$='.png'], .gallery a[href$='.jpeg'], .gallery a[href$='.gif']").attr('rel','gallery').fancybox();

// Initalize the Lightbox for any links with the 'video' class and provide improved video embed support
$(".video").fancybox({
    maxWidth        : 800,
    maxHeight       : 600,
    fitToView       : false,
    width           : '70%',
    height          : '70%',
    autoSize        : false,
    closeClick      : false,
    openEffect      : 'none',
    closeEffect     : 'none'
});

})(jQuery);
```

Then in my functions.php I added:

```
function m31_add_lightbox() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/lightbox.js', array( 'fancybox' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_style( 'lightbox-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/jquery.fancybox.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'm31_add_lightbox' );
```

And the HTML markup I used was:

```
<a href="http://www.aspenwebsites.com/lothlorien/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/M31-Efremov-2.jpg"><img src="http://www.aspenwebsites.com/lothlorien/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/M31-Efremov-2.jpg"></a>
```

According to the tutorial that all it takes. I thought I'd be required to add some class in order to trigger jQuery, but the tutorial had just as shown above.

As far as enqueing query itself - I'm assuming this is done by the twenty fourteen theme I'm using as a base, but to be honest, I'm not sure exactly how to verify that.

Comment: Well you can add a plugin in wordpress https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/
AS for your page you have just a link to the image, nothing more, how you want that to work? And show us some code, what you are trying to do :)

Comment: Sorry... I thought since I was folioing the tutorial the link to it would be sufficient to show the code bits... But I should have pasted it directly into my question. I just edited the question and added the code bits.

About the plugin - I'd like to learn to do it on my own, so trying to figure this all out.

Comment: well your javascript is not actually loading.  your css file is though.  first thing would be to get them loading.

Comment: @manishie - thanks for the tips. Could you suggest why the JS file wouldn't be loading? I checked the path and it is correct. I'm not entirely understanding how the wp_enque_script works, even though I've read the codex documentation. The part I'm confused about is parameter passed in the array. I assume those parameters indicate the sequences, meaning after what other script this one to be loaded.  Am I correct?


And going back to the JS files not loading - what do you think is done incorrectly?

Comment: the paramater array('jquery') is a list of handles for scripts that need to be loaded first for this to run.  so your first line says 'jquery' needs to be loaded, and the second line says 'fancybox' needs to be loaded.

Comment: it's possible they're not loading because the handles are duplicated.  try changing the handle 'fancybox' to 'fancyboxtest' and see if the first file loads.

Comment: and you've made sure that those 2 js files exist on the server in the same folder?  no typos in the filenames?

Comment: @manishie - thanks for taking time to look into my question. 

1) I did change the 'fancybox' handle  to 'fancyboxtest' , so I got this:

wp_enqueue_script( 'fancyboxtest', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/lightbox/lightbox.js', array( 'fancyboxtest' ), false, true );

Didn't help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61721/discussion-between-manishie-and-hanazair).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured out in our conversation, removing the last values in the wp_enqueue_scripts calls ( false, true ) did it.